# Select distinct rows in a data frame with only NA Values in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 cols.

```
ID1 <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4)

ID2 <- c(11,NA,12,NA,NA,NA)

Val <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")

DF <- data.frame(ID1,ID2,Val, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now, I need to extract unique rows which have ID2 as "NA". In this case, desired output will be **data frame with two rows i.e. ID1 = 3,4**. I tried below subset command which results into all the four rows with NA. Looking for ways to achieve the desired output.

```
DF2 <- subset(DF , is.na(ID2))
```

Comment: Is there any other feature that differentiates the last 2 rows of the data frame? Otherwise there will be no way to uniquely select just those rows.

Comment: Maybe something like `names(table(dat$id1[is.na(dat$id2)]) == 1)`

Comment: I don't think this question is very clear. Can you explain your rules for selecting rows a little bit more clearly?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 All the below answers suffice the need. First two are rather simple in terms implementation. Thanks

Comment: @string, then you should probably select one and mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by unique rows, you mean unique values of `ID1`, then this code makes the trick:

```
DF[which(!duplicated(DF$ID1) & is.na(DF$ID2)),]

  ID1 ID2 Val
5   3  NA   E
6   4  NA   F
```

If you prefer using `subset`, then this code gives the same output:

```
subset(DF , !duplicated(ID1) & is.na(ID2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
        group_by(ID1) %>%
        filter(n() == 1 & is.na(ID2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function to look up `ID1` groups which have all NAs in `ID2`, and then `return` the unique rows of them.

```
library(dplyr)

select_na <- function(df_sub) {
  if (any(!is.na(df_sub$ID2))) {
    return(df_sub[0,])
  }
  else {
    return(unique(df_sub))
  }
}

DF %>%
  group_by(ID1) %>%
  do(select_na(.))
```

gives exactly what you want.

Comment: Much more direct to just do `DF %>% group_by(ID1) %>% filter(sum(is.na(ID2)) == n())` if that's what they want. I think the OP needs to clarify what their conditions are.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 that's indeed much simpler, thanks for the reminder. However, my interpretation of extracting "unique rows which have ID2 as 'NA'" is selecting rows which have unique values in `ID1` or `Val`. With your approach, two rows with the same `ID1` and `Val` will be both included while mine includes only one of them. Let's wait and see if OP has further clarification.